# Woocommerce Single Payment Link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I’m attempting to replace the regular payment and invoice email
template links in Woocommerce. I attempted to follow the instructions in the this article (https://anchor.host/speedy-checkouts-with-woocommerce-subscriptions/)

but received an error message in line 5 $customer_id

```
<?php

$order_id = get_query_var( 'callback' );
$key      = $_GET['key'];

// Loads user and key from order
$customer_id = get_field( '_customer_user', $order_id );
$order_key   = get_field( '_order_key', $order_id );

// Loads order
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

// Fetch payment url
$payment_url = $order->get_checkout_payment_url();

// Fetch user
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $customer_id );

if ( $user and $order_key == $key ) {

    // Login as new user
    wp_set_current_user( $user->ID, $user->user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );

    // Redirect to payment url
    wp_redirect( $payment_url );

} else {

    // Redirect to homepage
    wp_redirect( get_home_url() );

}
```

Just for some context, Currently, I handle the signup process for my customers.I just would like to generate and send my customers their subscription without having to login - simply click a link and enter payment info.

Thanks in advance,

Steve

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be nice if you [edit] this question to explain the exact things you tried in the page you linked, where/when you received the error message, and what the error message was. This will make it easier for others to answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, and I just edited my post!

Comment: Thanks for the code. It would also be nice if you edited in further details of the exact error message you're getting.